# Envío de mas de una variable de php en ajax que se actualiza automáticamente sin reiniciar página

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo el siguiente programa que sirve para mostrar búsqueda sin reiniciar el formulario:

```
//Esta parte va en Head dentro del HTML.

$(document).ready(function(){

        var consulta;

         //hacemos focus al campo de búsqueda
        $("#busqueda").focus();

        //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
        $("#busqueda").keyup(function(e){

              //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
              consulta = $("#busqueda").val();

              //hace la búsqueda

              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "buscar.php",
                    data: "b="+consulta,
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                          //imagen de carga
                          $("#resultado").html("
<p align="center"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /></p>
"); }, error: function(){alert("error petición ajax");}, success: function(data){ $("#resultado").empty(); $("#resultado").append(data); } }); }); }); ?&gt;


//Esta parte va dentro de BODY.

<input id="busqueda" type="text" />


//Por último esta parte va en programa llamado buscar.php.

<?php

            $buscar = $_POST['b'];

            if(!empty($buscar)) {
                        buscar($buscar);
            }

            function buscar($b) {
                        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'root');
                        mysql_select_db('base_de_datos', $con);

                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$b."%'",$con);

                        $contar = mysql_num_rows($sql);

                        if($contar == 0){
                                    echo "No se han encontrado resultados para '<b>".$b."</b>'.";
                        }else{
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                                $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                                                $id = $row['id'];

                                                echo $id." - ".$nombre."<br /><br />";   
                                    }
                        }
            }

?>
```

Funciona a la perfección pero necesito o enviar mas de una variable o que me permita ingresas sessiones de php al programa buscar.php, he intentado con las sessiones abriendo dentro del programa buscar.php la session (session_start();) pero no muestra valor alguno dentro de la variable session, de igual forma espero que este programa sea de utilidad para alguien, si tienen dudas sobre como adaptarlo a sus necesidades con gusto les apoyare y si alguien conoce el método idóneo para poder pasar mas variables o bien que pueda mostrarse los valores de variables session estaría excelente, gracias.

El día de ayer intente incrementar la cantidad de valores que se envían al programa buscar.php pero no obtuve éxito:

```
 //hace la búsqueda



$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "buscar.php",
            data: "b="+consulta,
```

Modifique de varias formas Data: "b="+consulta, agregando

```
data: "b="+consulta, "c="+valor,   o
data: {b: consulta, c:valor},  o
data: "b="+consulta, c:valor,
```

entre otras cosas pero el valor no llega al programa buscar.php

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer? no se te entiende la pregunta, podrías editarla para entender mejor el problema que tienes y a que quieres llegar?

Comment: El script que va en head envia solo un valor al programa buscar.php y necesito que se envíen dos o mas.

Comment: puedes enviar campos ocultos `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: O como alternativa, que el programa buscar.php se pueda reflejar el valor de una session de php, lo he intentado pero la variable muestra no tener valor aun cuando inicio session y declaro correctamente los valores.

Comment: Lo siento pero si fuese tan sencillo no estaria posteando esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Para enviar más de un valor en un AJAX con JQuery usa un `object literal` en `data`:

```
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "buscar.php",
                data: {b: consulta, c: otra_variable, d: 10}
```

La cuestión me parece que es ¿de dónde sacas el valor que quieres enviar como `c` o  `d`

En cuanto a tu pregunta de las sesiones, la información de las sesiones **no viaja** en los headers POST o GET y no puede ser modificada o accesada por JQuery. La información dentro de `$_SESSION` se guarda dentro de tu servidor web y se usa cuando hay un match entre el ID de la cookie (que se envía en el HTTP Request) y alguna de todas las sesiones que pueda tener tu servidor guardadas.

Si pones más información de la que debes será fácil para cualquier hacker de bolsillo robar una sesión de tu página.

Por último está de más decirlo pero tu pregunta está demasiado abierta y necesitarías especificar más cual es el resultado que quieres obtener y que has intentado.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, el presente script como les menciono solo envía un valor en una variable sin reiniciar el formulario o la pagina actual, pero necesito enviar dos valores en lugar de uno, he tratado de modificar el script para esta tarea pero deja de funcionar, trate con sesiones para evitar modificar el código pero el valor de la session puede ser leída y mostrada en cualquier programa php excepto en el programa buscar.php, la idea es utilizar dos valores para filtrar una búsqueda a la tabla deseada.

Comment: En la solución que te presento puedes enviar N valores usando un `object literal`. Justo ahora envías 1 valor porque envías  `data: "b="+consulta,` usando un object literal se convierte a `data: {b: consulta},` pero así como b, puedes poner una variable `c` o variable `patoloco` y mandar el valor que quieras dentro de ella. No le veo otra forma de resolverlo.

Comment: Bro te agradezco mucho el comentario, pero lo he intentado como me haz indicado, al igual de seguir las indicaciones de @Cig pero desafortunadamente no lo he podido hacer funcionar, admito que algo se me puede estar escapando, pero por mas que le muevo y le investigo no da resultado, pero de verdad agradezco la ayuda que ambos me han proporcionado, continuare intentado, en caso de tener éxito les avisare, gracias.

Comment: Estás posteando a `buscar.php`, al inicio de ese script puedes poner `exit(var_dump($_POST));` y hacer un llamado... ahí te dará las variables que estás enviando. Pero es que en verdad es confuso entender lo que necesitas, recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo explicando que sucede en cada paso para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Bro aparece esto  array(1) { ["b"]=> string(1) "t" }
al teclear t pero no muestra el valor de c, seguire probando, saludos.

Comment: En este caso  `data: {b: consulta, c: otra_variable, d: 10}` c sería otra variable previamente establecida pero si la variable no está definida entonces no se envía nada. Intenta con `data: {b: consulta, c: 'otra_variable', d: 10}` en este ejemplo tendrías que ver `array(3) { ["b"]=> string(1) "t", ["b"]=> string(3) "otra_variable", ["b"]=> string(2) "10" }`

Comment: Ya lo he intentado pero no da resultado, creo que el detalle es que muestra resultados conforme se van tecleando sin actualizar ni el formulario ni la pagina, y sin boton form, al principio pensé que las sesiones podrían ser una solución pero tal vez la cuestion de que se actualiza automaticamente sea el factor determinante para evitar que las sessiones puedan ser leidas, pero en fin, continuo en la causa, muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Haz pensado autocomplete de JQUERY?

Comment: @Solrac Ragnarockradio tal vez aun no soluciono el problema para lo cual abri esta pregunta, pero si que me abriste los ojos con respecto a las sessiones que estan vulnerables y a la vista, me he puesto a corregir ese hecho, de antemano muchas gracias Bro, fuen un dato muy acertado que valoro mucho, saludos y bendiciones.

Comment: @Cig La verdad no habia contemplado manejar autocomplete de jquery pero lo voy a checar, muchas gracias Bro, si encuentro la solución les aviso.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formdata">
   <input id="busqueda" type="text" name="buscar"/>
   <input id="campo_oculto1" name="oculto1" type="hidden" value="loquequieras"/>
   <input id="campo_oculto2" name="oculto2" type="hidden" value="loquequieras"/>  
</form>
```

Dentro de tu Javascript

```
//Cambiaría tu petición ajax por
$.post("enviar.php",$("#formdata").serialize(),function(res)
```

Y en el PHP obtendría

```
$buscar = isset($_POST['buscar']) ? $_POST['buscar'] : null;
$oculto1 = isset($_POST['oculto1']) ? $_POST['oculto1'] : null;
$oculto2 = isset($_POST['oculto2']) ? $_POST['oculto2'] : null;
```

Comment: Bro gracias por tus comentarios, los he puesto en practica pero no he tenido éxito, continuare intentando, en caso de lograrlo te avisare, gracias.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con lo que ya hayas intentado @Stravos77